# Avoid "unused typedef" warnings when wrapping with swig

Tags: python, c++, wrapper, swig

I am using swig as a wrapper to call c++ functions from my python code. My problem is, that a lot of warnings of the following type are generated, because I included part of the Boost library.

```
/usr/local/include/boost/math/special_functions/bessel.hpp:744:4: warning: unused typedef
  'boost_static_assert_typedef_747' [-Wunused-local-typedef]
```

Is there a way to avoid this? I guess using

```
-isystem /usr/local/include
```

as a flag instead of

```
-I /usr/local/include
```

would solve the problem. But where do I have to add it? The latter option is currently implemented in my setup.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
setup.py file for SWIG spherical_overlap
"""

from distutils.core import setup, Extension


spherical_overlap_module = Extension('_spherical_overlap',
                       sources=['spherical_overlap_wrap.cxx', 'spherical_overlap.cpp'],
                           swig_opts=['-c++', '-py3'],
                           extra_compile_args =['-lboost_system '],
                           include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include'],
                           )

setup (name = 'spherical_overlap',
       version = '0.1',
       author      = "SWIG Docs",
       description = """Simple swig spherical_overlap from docs""",
       ext_modules = [spherical_overlap_module],
       py_modules = ["spherical_overlap"],
       )
```

Comment: Thanks, that is enough for me. I added `-Wno-unused-local-typedef` to `extra_compile_args`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want just to avoid warnings you can add `-Wno-unused-local-typedef` option